# Add custom object as option inside dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I'm having some kind of a bad time where i need to append some json objects as selectlistitems inside a dropdownlist that is different from where i display these json objects.

I managed to retrieve all data, but i dont know how to translate all the information from one kind of element to another. Currently i set up something like this:

All objects that come from my JsonResult method in controller comes like this:

[Jsonresult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GONO.png)

and the current format for my dropdownlist is as follows:

[Dropdownlist selection from controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MHY3.png)

For right now I have come to the current state:
i created an array that stores all my objects and convert them to  tags, but as i went debugging my array looks like this:

[Array from ajax as option tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woeHY.png)

My Ajax Request is working as follows:

```
function GetContratosFiltro() {
        $("#id_contrato_aplicativo").empty();
        $("#ckSelecionarTdsContratosFiltro").removeAttr("disabled");
        var array_sistema = $('#id_sistema').val();
        var array_build = $('#id_build_verus').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetContratosFiltros")',
                dataType: "json",
                //data: "{ 'id_sistema': '"  + array_sistema + "'," + "'id_build_verus': '" + array_build + "'}",
                data: JSON.stringify({ id_sistema: array_sistema || null, id_build_verus: array_build || null }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (contratos) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(contratos));
                    var formoption = [];
                    content = contratos;
                    $.each(contratos, function (index, element) {
                        console.log(element);
                        var xx = $('<div class="checkbox">' +
                            '<input value="' + element.id_contrato + '" type="checkbox" name="' + element.contrato + '" class="form-check-input" id="' + index + '" checked>' +
                            '<label class="form-check-label" for="' + index + '">' + element.contrato + '</label>' +
                            '</div >');
                        $('#id_contrato_aplicativo').append(xx);
                        for (var i = 0; i < contratos.length; i++) {
                            formoption[index] = " < option value = '" + element.id_contrato + "' id='" + element.id_contrato + "' > " + element.contrato + "</option >";
                        }

                    });
                    array = formoption;
                    $("#ckSelecionarTdsContratosFiltro").prop('checked', true);
                    console.log('formoption: ' + formoption);
                    console.log('array: ' + array);
                    console.log(content);
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    //alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);
                }
            });
        }
```

My output on the filter modal is, for example:
[Modal filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jPAd.png)

On this code: id_contrato_aplicativo is a div where i store all the results from jsonresult query and displays them as checkboxes divs with input and labels, by this bootstrap documentation [Checkboxes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/checks-radios/). My HTML consists into a modal with the filter options with two fields that send information to controller and the main dropdown just gets all information from regular query in controller, but i'm using a custom class called select2 which create the layout for my application and generate the multiselect dropdownlist as a  element with each new

showing as a block inside dropdown selection, like the image below:

[Dropdown result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89lXI.png)

This code is where i generate all  tags for each item from ajax call and below is the function that i am testing right now.

```
for (var i = 0; i < contratos.length; i++) {
                            formoption[index] = " < option value = '" + element.id_contrato + "' id='" + element.id_contrato + "' > " + element.contrato + "</option >";
                        }
```

```
    $('#btnTransf').click(function () {
        console.log('clicou no botão!')
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i].appendTo('#id_contrato select');
            $('#id_contrato').select();
            //appends to select if parent div has id dropdown
            //return !$("#id_contrato_aplicativo :checked").remove().appendTo('#id_contrato');
        }
        //return !$("#id_contrato_aplicativo :checked").remove().appendTo('#id_contrato');
    });
```

UPDATE:
i have managed to locate the correct element  and turn out that i only need to pass all elements already formated array variable with all elements as  tags inside id_contrato  element.

Removed useless info

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it to work by making an event bind on a button that gets each element of my array of already formatted objects and with its ids as values from  tags.

Array Structure example ( from ajax call):

```
array = []; //external variable
//put this susccess inside your call from ajax, considering a JsonResult as your controller method
success: function (contratos) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(contratos));
                    var formoption = [];
                    content = contratos;
                    $.each(contratos, function (index, element) {
                        console.log(element);
                        var xx = $('<div class="checkbox">' +
                            '<input value="' + element.id_contrato + '" type="checkbox" name="' + element.contrato + '" class="form-check-input" id="' + index + '" checked>' +
                            '<label class="form-check-label" for="' + index + '">' + element.contrato + '</label>' +
                            '</div >');
                        $('#id_contrato_aplicativo').append(xx);
                        for (var i = 0; i < contratos.length; i++) {
                            formoption[index] = " <option value='" + element.id_contrato + "'selected> " + element.contrato + "</option>";
                        }

                    });
                    array = formoption;
                    $("#ckSelecionarTdsContratosFiltro").prop('checked', true);
                    console.log('formoption: ' + formoption);
                    console.log('array: ' + array);
                    console.log(content);
                }
```

Code:

```
    $('#btnTransf').click(function () {
        console.log('test to check if click successful!')
        $.each(array, function (index, element) {
            console.log(element);
            $('#id_contrato').append(element);
            $('#id_contrato').select();
        });

   });
```